# Unable to post form data to RDS MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Hello anyone who can help (or having the same issue).

I have a form on my website I need to store the data in a database.
I have no problems when using any other database service but when using an Amazon RDS Database I have no luck.

This php file is used to send the data to the database.

```
 <?php

$dbhost = "xxxx.xxxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com";
$dbuser = "username";
$dbpass = "pasword";
$userid = $_GET['UniqueID'];
$username = $_GET['name'];
$useremail = $_GET['email'];
$userphone = $_GET['phone'];
$userref = $_GET['refid'];

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO landing_post (`useid`, `name`, `email`, `phone`, `refid`) VALUES ('$userid', '$username', '$useremail', '$userphone', '$userref')";

mysql_select_db('bunker');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

After the form is submitted to the original post action, it opens the below url.

```
https://example.com.au/test/post.php?&UniqueID=10020&name=burger&email=test%40mvmedia.com&phone=1800+000+000&refid=28383
```

The $_GET functions fill out the data using the variables in the url.

When running the php from a cpanel based server I get this error.

```
Could not connect: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxxxx.xxxxxxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (111)
```

When running the php from a AWS EC2 instance I don't even get a error readout.

Any assistance or insight would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers,
Andy

Comment: Stop using SQL because you are print to sql injections. It is deprecated. Look at this link my friend:https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp. What I would also recommend is you erasing everything and just leave the connection part of the script and run it. See if it still gives you the same error.

Comment: Hey JeanPaul98, I have tried running my php stripped down to see if i can get a connection, but with no avail. Also i just tried using your recommended code purely to check the connection... still the same error.

Comment: I found this article see if it can help you https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.rds.html also found this on another question on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582706/connect-to-amazon-rds-with-php see if either link will help you

Comment: Did you set the "Publicly accessible" flag to true and make sure your security group is accepting connections from your web server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Shout out to JeanPaul98 who put me on the right path. After trial and many errors, i found the below code solved the issue.

```
<?php

$userid = $_GET['UniqueID'];
$username = $_GET['name'];
$useremail = $_GET['email'];
$userphone = $_GET['phone'];
$userref = $_GET['refid'];

$link = mysqli_connect('xxxxx.xxxxxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com', 'User', 'password','database');

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Check if server is alive
if (mysqli_ping($link))
  {
  echo "Connection is ok!";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error: ". mysqli_error($link);
  }




 mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO table (`useid`, `name`, `email`, `phone`, `refid`) VALUES ('$userid', '$username', '$useremail', '$userphone', '$userref')") 
 or die(mysqli_error($link));


  echo "Entered data successfully\n";


mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

The main change was I stopped using mysql and rather used mysqli. There are also some structural changes to make the code to work with mysqli. For others having a similar issues here are a few things to check.

- You have opened a inbound port for the IP in the security group of the RDS Database.
- The Database is publicly accessible.
- That your php version has PDO_MYSQL installed, or compatible driver (more details here
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.rds.html)

Comment: Please note that `The Database is publicly accessible.` is not necessary and almost always should NOT be publicly accessible (and ONLY if you know what you are doing and have a valid reason). You just need to ensure the security group allows access to the database. `PDO_MYSQL` is also not necessary unless you are using PDO.